# Cannot convert IEnumerable type to IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I don't understand why I can't assign a value returned from method of `IEnumerable<Person>` to the same type. I am getting the message:

> Cannot convert source type `IEnumerable<Person>` to target type `IEnumerable<Person>`.

Can anyone please suggest what's wrong with this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(IEnumerable<int> Ids)
{
    return FindAll(m => Ids.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
}
```

After calling this method trying to assign to the value of same type:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = _myRepository.GetPeople(listOfIds);
```

I can assign to var, but I would like to declare this variable in class scope, so I am stuck.

Comment: Are they of IEnumerable Person? That's the only thing I can imagine that would be different without actually seeing the actual output...

Comment: What does `FindAll` do/look like?

Comment: Is it possible you have two different Person types?

Comment: Don't you have different person classes? It seems like person is not a person

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple Person classes in your solution. This could result from referencing/loading different variants/versions of the same assembly.

Comment: As the class you're querying is called `myRepository`, i'm betting you haven't converted you DTO to your POCO, which are both called `Person`.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is EXACTLY as you listed?  It is likely FindAll().ToList() returns IEnumerable, instead of an IEnumerable<Person>.

Comment: @Russ - `.ToList()` would return a `List<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that was the trick.  I didn't realise that there were to implementations of Person class.  Namespace addition helped. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to use your Person with namespace:

```
public IEnumerable<[Namespace]> GetPeople(IEnumerable<int> Ids)
{
    return FindAll(m => Ids.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
}

IEnumerable<[Namespace].Person> people = _myRepository.GetPeople(listOfIds);
```

[Namespace] - namespace where `Person` type is stored

Comment: This would only be the case if the OP has multiple definitions for `Person` in different namespaces.  OP has not indicated that is the case, so while it's a possible solution it's not (yet, at least) a *definitive* solution.

Comment: @Tim given the error message, that's the only explanation I can think of.